# Is there any method to pass variable other than get and post in php?

Tags: php

I just want to know is there any other method other than get and post method to pass variable from one page to another page. I know there is session method but i dont want that.
And my another doubt is whethere session is secure or not. Many of them suggest session is not secure. Is it reliable or not? When to use session and when not?
login1.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<form name="login_form"  method="post"  id="frmLoginAdmin"           action="login2.php">
<input type="hidden" value="abcd" name="abcda">
<input  type="submit">  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

login2.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body onLoad="auto();">
<form action="login1.php" method="POST" name="myform">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['abcda']; ?>" name="you know">
<input type="hidden" value="somevalue" name="what todo here">
<input type="hidden" value="somevalue" name="so do it">
<input type="hidden" value="somevalue" name="ok">
</form>
</body>
</html>
<script>
function auto() {
  document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
```

This is the condition. First i used get method to pass values back to login1.php.But now i dont want my user to see what variables is passes. So i uses above method but it first redirects to login2.php which shows a empty page for a fraction of second to the user then only it redirects to the login1.php.This is my issue thats why i am asking for any other alternate method to pass variable

Comment: Yes there are other HTTP methods for example `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE`

Comment: Sessions are a lot more secure than post and/or get since they're server side.

Comment: "I know there is session method but i dont want that". Why not? If you're asking for an alternative to something that everyone generally uses, you need to explain why it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: But many says that session causes performance issues and its vulnerable. Is it true?

Comment: No, not sure where you heard that @Sam but the session superglobal was created to handle exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Daan  +10 for you and @Andrew. And YES! Those (`PUT`, `PATCH`, `DELETE`) are Valid HTTP Methods, but it would be most likely that he wouldn't be using or needing them except if he is working with some Special REST API or something along those Lines. @Andrew's comment is most likely what he'd be needing... and well... to add to the mix.... there are `COOKIES` as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are no other ways with HTTP (except what HTTP allows, as already mentioned).

But there are many other ways to transfer data from server to server, like FTP or establishing a direct socket connection.

Note that you will need install/configure such additional ways, and maybe not only on the server (for communication through a firewall, you will also need to allow the used ports)

Answer (score 0):

You may use encrypted cookies: https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/cookie to store an encoded key. Based on that decoded key you can save and read from database+Memcache layer

Answer (score -1):

**Session :**

A session is stored on the server and cannot be accessed by the user (client). It is used to store information across the site such as login sessions. It can be used to store information in the server side, and pass between different php scripts

Note that session creates a session cookie for identification like `PHPSESSID`, which may reveal server-side scripting language used, which most people prefer not to reveal. To not reveal, we can change this cookie name from php. Also, by stealing that cookie, someone may hijack the session. So, session should be used properly by verifying it. If session verifying is done, you may prevent hijacking and use it securely.

**For Secure Usage:**

To use sessions securely, you can follow this blog which shows how sessions can be verified and prevented from being hijacked.

> http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions

Comment: From that secure tutorial `$https = isset($secure) ? $secure : isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']);` is kinda wrong.

Comment: yea but, what i wanted to show was,, checking ip stored in session and ip of the user, to see if the session was hijacked..